# List of Dictionaries Python: Append a new key, value pair to dictionary if existing key, value pair matches

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

```
original_list = [{"record1": 1, "record2": "loremipsum1", "record3": "loremipsum2", "record4": "loremipsum3"}, 
{"record1": 2, "record2": "loremipsum4", "record3": "loremipsum5", "record4": "loremipsum6"}, 
{"record1": 3, "record2": "loremipsum7", "record3": "loremipsum8", "record4": "loremipsum9"}, 
{"record1": 4, "record2": "loremipsum10", "record3": "loremipsum12", "record4": "loremipsum13"}, 
{"record1": 5, "record2": "loremipsum11", "record3": "loremipsum12", "record4": "loremipsum13"}]
```

```
to_append = [{"record1": 1, "new_record": "new1"},
{"record1": 2, "new_record": "new2"}]
```

```
output = [{"record1": 1, "record2": "loremipsum1", "record3": "loremipsum2", "record4": "loremipsum3", "new_record": "new1"}, 
{"record1": 2, "record2": "loremipsum4", "record3": "loremipsum5", "record4": "loremipsum6", "new_record": "new2"}, 
{"record1": 3, "record2": "loremipsum7", "record3": "loremipsum8", "record4": "loremipsum9"}, 
{"record1": 4, "record2": "loremipsum10", "record3": "loremipsum12", "record4": "loremipsum13"}, 
{"record1": 5, "record2": "loremipsum11", "record3": "loremipsum12", "record4": "loremipsum13"}]
```

The output is to append the `new_record` to the dictionary in the list if value of `record1` field is the same and do nothing if `new_record` does not exists. Better if itertools is used.

I tried a few solutions but it returns an array with appended dictionary only if `new_record` exists - ignores all other dictionaries.

Could anyone help with it please? TIA

Comment: Based on the example data - do you think all records in `array_to_append ` should be added?

Comment: You have an extra `{}` around the second dictionary in `array_to_append`. That's not valid.

Comment: Should "if new_record does not exist" be "if record1 value does not exist"?

Comment: FYI these are lists, not arrays.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Barmar Its a typo, new to python - I assumed both are the same. Made the changes as suggested. Thank you.

Comment: @balderman Yes, all the records should be added

Comment: @Engineero, I created a new list and appended the dictionaries if there is a match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check every dictionary in `original_array` against every dictionary in `array_to_append`; if you find a match between `record1` in any specific pair, then `update` the original one:

```
for d1 in original_array:
    for d2 in array_to_append:
        if d1['record1'] == d2['record1']:
            d1.update(d2)
```

Resulting in:

```
>>> original_array 
[{'record1': 1,
  'record2': 'loremipsum1',
  'record3': 'loremipsum2',
  'record4': 'loremipsum3',
  'new_record': 'new1'},
 {'record1': 2,
  'record2': 'loremipsum4',
  'record3': 'loremipsum5',
  'record4': 'loremipsum6',
  'new_record': 'new2'},
 {'record1': 3,
  'record2': 'loremipsum7',
  'record3': 'loremipsum8',
  'record4': 'loremipsum9'},
 {'record1': 4,
  'record2': 'loremipsum10',
  'record3': 'loremipsum12',
  'record4': 'loremipsum13'},
 {'record1': 5,
  'record2': 'loremipsum11',
  'record3': 'loremipsum12',
  'record4': 'loremipsum13'}]
```

A few things to keep in mind:

- This is modifying `original_array` and the dictionaries inside, not creating new objects.
- This raises a `KeyError` if any dictionary does not have a `'record1'` key.  If you expect some dictionaries to not have that field, you will have to add handling that.
- If there is more than one entry in `array_to_append` with a matching `'record1'` for a given dictionary, you could have issues with the "new_records" overwriting one another.

Comment: This works, Thanks Tom!!

Comment: @thinkpythonxoxo sure thing; please accept the answer if your question has been solved

Comment: Done! Thanks :D